# Access parent from Ajax Loaded Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using Ajax to load a page inside my div, I can't access the parent window to execute a function. Is this possible, or just from iframe?

Not Working - Code:

```
var columns = $( "td:contains('xvalue')" ).length;

if (typeof columns == 'undefined' || columns == null || columns == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    window.parent.focus();
    window.parent.alert(columns);
}
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test/index.html",
}).done(function (data) {
    $(".mailcontrol").html(data);
});
```

Comment: can u show your ajax code as well as html ?

Comment: Where is your "not working code" - is it in the calling page? If so, your var columns = ... line may be selecting an element that does not yet exist because it hasn't finished loading via your AJAX request.

Comment: `window.parent` only works in reference to an iframe. In order to move to an element *that exists in the same DOM tree*, use `jQuery('.selector').parent();`

since you are already using jquery; the vanilla way to do this is `getElementById()`

Comment: I can't call my function if the loading hasn't finished 'cause, for testing, I use a button inside the div loaded by ajax. mopsyd, I'm trying with your suggestion. Thanks!